# Webpack2 can't resolve file in pathname

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-2

I have having a strange issue I can't seem to resolve.

I am getting this error:

```
Error: Can't resolve 'store/configureStore' in '/Users/samboy/company/oh-frontend/app'
```

My webpack file looks like this:

```
   name: 'browser',
    context: path.join(__dirname, '..', '..', '..', 'app'),
    entry: {
      app: './client'
    },
    output: {
      // The output directory as absolute path
      path: assetsPath,
      // The filename of the entry chunk as relative path inside the output.path directory
      filename: '[name].js',
      // The output path from the view of the Javascript
      publicPath: publicPath

    },

    module: {
      loaders: commonLoaders
    },
    resolve: {
      modules: [
        path.resolve(__dirname, '..', '..', '..', 'app'),
        'node_modules'
      ],
      extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx', '.css']
    },
    plugins: [
        // extract inline css from modules into separate files
        new ExtractTextPlugin('styles/bundled-modules.css'),
        // files in global directory should be concatenated into one file for prod
        new CopyWebpackPlugin([
            { from: 'fonts/', to: 'fonts/' }
            , { from: '_web/css/global/fonts.css', to: 'styles/fonts.css' }
            , { from: '_web/css/vendors', to: 'styles/vendors' }
        ]),
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
          compressor: {
            warnings: false
          }
        }),
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
          __DEVCLIENT__: false,
          __DEVSERVER__: false,
          __PLATFORM_WEB__: true,
          __PLATFORM_IOS__: false
        }),
        new InlineEnviromentVariablesPlugin({ NODE_ENV: 'production' }),function()
    {
        this.plugin("done", function(stats)
        {
            if (stats.compilation.errors && stats.compilation.errors.length)
            {
                console.log(stats.compilation.errors);
                process.exit(1);
            }
            // ...
        });
    }
    ],
    postcss: postCSSConfig
  }
```

The file is certainly present in that folder. It worked fine with webpack. It doesn't seem to work with webpack2 though.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing because you didn't post your app file, but can you change the import statement in the app file to "./store/configureStore"?

Comment: I guess you're right. I added it and started getting errors in other places. With that said, is there a way so I don't have to add './'? That's going to make me modify 1000s of files. It seemed to work fine with webpack, but only an issue with webpack2

Comment: ./ Means it is a relative path and not an alias. Imagine the confusion between "jquery" and "./jquery", for instance. Your best bet would be to use a find and replace utility in your IDE